# Colores sección navegación android en Flutter

Tags: flutter

Recientemente vi el cambio de estilo que tuvo la aplicación aimp de android y me gustaría saber cómo hacer algo similar en Flutterpara practicar.

Sobre todo, me llama la atención que la barra de estado aparece con el color superior, pero los botones de navegación de android también cambian de color y nunca he visto en ningun código como cambiar los colores.

Agradezco cualquier ayuda que me puedan brindar para seguir aprendiendo.

[image: captura de pantalla aimp app]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eso lo puedes hacer usando la clase `SystemChrome` con los parametros `systemNavigationBarColor` para el color de los controles y `statusBarColor` para el color de la barra de esto.

Ejemplo:

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.blue, // navigation bar color
      statusBarColor: Colors.pink, // status bar color
    ));
```

Puedes agregarlo antes de crear tu widget the `MaterialApp`.